# R: Extract columns of a dataframe through string matching

Tags: r, match, subset

I have a dataframe where the variables are character-strings. How can I extract only those columns where at least one value matches a particular string? For example, in the dataframe below, I want a match of the string "AB", i.e. I want to subset out another dataframe containing the columns V1, V2 and V5.

```
V1      V2      V3      V4      V5
ABCD    ABEF    EFGJ    AFASD   JLKJLXKJ
LKJAF   ROGIJ   GREJWI  SDFS    ABKLJKJX
AFSD    JLASDF  JKLJ    OIJPOI  AFSD
```

Comment: Use grepl with sapply? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know where to start. I have 389 variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you can apply `grepl` with required pattern to each column:

```
> sapply(data, function (x) grepl('AB', x))
        V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

You can simplify above result by wrapping `grepl` call with `any`

```
> sapply(data, function (x) any(grepl('AB', x)))
   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5 
TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

With vector like this you can easily extract required columns:

```
data[, sapply(data, function (x) any(grepl('AB', x)))]
```

And the result is:

```
     V1     V2       V5
1  ABCD   ABEF JLKJLXKJ
2 LKJAF  ROGIJ ABKLJKJX
3  AFSD JLASDF     AFSD
```

Answer (score 4):

At this point, my answer doesn't add much, but I was on my phone when I posted the comment, so I didn't feel comfortable posting an actual answer.

Anyway, here's what I would have suggested. It's pretty much the same concept as @zero323's answer, but uses `sapply` or `vapply` instead of `apply`, since those are likely to be more efficient on columns of a `data.frame`:

```
mydf[vapply(mydf, function(x) any(grepl("AB", x)), vector(length = 1))]
```

or

```
mydf[sapply(mydf, function(x) any(grepl("AB", x)))]
```

---

To show the speed difference, let's try it on a larger `data.frame`, this one being 500 rows by 500 columns.

```
library(microbenchmark)
fun1a <- function() mydf[vapply(mydf, function(x) any(grepl("AB", x)), vector(length = 1))]
fun1b <- function() mydf[sapply(mydf, function(x) any(grepl("AB", x)))]
fun2 <- function() mydf[, apply(mydf, 2, function (x) any(grepl('AB', x)))]

set.seed(1)
nrow <- 500
ncol <- 500
x <- sample(8, nrow*ncol, replace = TRUE)
y <- lapply(x, function(z) paste(sample(LETTERS, z, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(y, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nrow))

microbenchmark(fun1a(), fun1b(), fun2(), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min        lq    median       uq      max neval
#  fun1a()  75.46204  82.84732 101.22437 115.8292 120.5349    10
#  fun1b()  75.92004  85.82025  99.31647 108.5303 310.0216    10
#   fun2() 134.82356 168.44435 182.88842 196.4751 207.9986    10
identical(fun1a(), fun2())
# [1] TRUE
identical(fun1b(), fun2())
# [1] TRUE
```

`vapply` usually gives a bit of a speed boost, but in this case, it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Very impressive. Good to know, and thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` this prints column V1,V2 and V5 if column V5 contains `AB`

```
awk '$NF~"AB" {print $1,$2,$5}' OFS="\t" file
LKJAF   ROGIJ   ABKLJKJX
```

Comment: I do not know what `r` is but `grep` is a unix tool and `awk` does much that the `grep` does.

Comment: Good point. I've removed the wrong tag. `grep` is also an R function.